# Order of senses according to sanathan dharma

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, indriyas

In sanathan dharma, there are atleast six sensory organs: manas, ears, skin, eye, tongue, nose. We are considering only the five physical sensory organs for our discussion, keeping manas aside.

Modern science belives that there may be no natural ordering of sensory organs among all cultures. [1](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/11/181105160852.htm), [2](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Joukowsky_Institute/courses/13things/7167.html)

> The accepted hierarchy of human senses -- sight, hearing, touch,
> taste and smell -- is not universally true across all cultures, new
> research shows.

Consider the following statement of Vyasa

> Having first subdued the mind, the Yogin should then proceed to subdue
> his ears, then his eyes, then his tongue, and then his nose.
>
> [[Section 240, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b067.htm)

The order given by vyasa is: ears (1), eyes (2), tongue (3), nose (4). He didn't tell about skin.

Is it the ordering based on the power of sensory organs? If yes, why skin is not considered?

If no, do scriptures mention the order of sensory organs based on their power/influence on the jiva?

Comment: vyasa's order is correct, although the translation might have omitted touch. do you have original Sanskrit verse ?

Comment: Yeah, I will try to update the question @mar

Comment: See Aitreya Upanishad Chapter 1, Mundaka Upanishad Chapter 2, and Brahma Sutras 2.4..5-7. There are two problems with your question; first, what you are referring to as physical sense organs are not considered sense organs in the Vedas, they are considered the instruments of the sense organs; second, the order to 'control' the organs is not directly correlated with their order of creation.

Answer (score 5):

Order of creation of Pancha Bhutas, [Taitriya Upanishad 2.1.1](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/upanishad/upan_06.html)

> akasadvayuh | vayoragnih | agnerapah | adbhyah prthivi

Pancha Tanmatra associated with Pancha Bhuta, Tarka Sangraha

> Shabda Sparsha Rupa Rasa Gandha

[image: Shabda]
[image: Tanmatra]

Pancha Indriya associated with Pancha Tanmatra:

Ears Skin Eyes Tongue Nose

[image]